# PHP Mailing data from SQL Tables

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron

I'm no php/mysql expert, but I can usually get things to work with some research and trial, but this one I can't seem to get to work like I want...

I run a classifieds website and I plan to setup a cron job (cron job I can do) and send a reminder email to users who ad has been posted for 30 days. I got the date working good using date_sub and curdate. My query pulls all the tables I want to use in my email from the database whose ad is 30 days old.

I can get the email to send with the posters name, email and html message, but It's only sending to the first email address it query's. I'm assuming it's a loop issue? But I can't seem to figure it out.

My script is posted below - I apologize for the messiness as I said I'm no expert in this, but I got it mostly working how I want with the exception it will only send to the first ad that shows up.

Most all of the table names in the sql query contain data I plan to use in the html message.

```
    <?php
        header("Content-type: text/plain");

    // OPEN DATABASE
        define('DB_HOST','localhost');
        define('DB_USER','');
        define('DB_PASS','');
        define('DB_NAME','');

        mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Connetion to database failed!");
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME); 

        joinDateFilter();

    // WHOSE AD IS 30 DAYS OLD
        function joinDateFilter(){
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT name,title,email,idPost,password FROM oc_posts WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) = CAST(insertDate AS date)");
            $mail_to = "$email";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo $row['name']." - ".$row['title']." - ".$row['email']."\n";
                echo $mail_to = $row['email'].", ";
                echo $title=$row["title"];
                echo $name=$row["name"];
                echo $idPost=$row["idPost"];
                echo $password=$row["password"];
            }
            if (!empty($mail_to)){
                sendEmail($mail_to,$email,$name,$title,$idPost,$password);
            }
        }

    // SEND EMAIL
        function sendEmail($mail_to,$email,$name,$title,$idPost,$password) {
            $mail_to ="$mail_to";
            $email ="$email";
            $name = "$name";
            $title = "$title";
            $idPost = "$idPost";
            $password = "$password";
            $from    = "no-reply@2tradeit.com";
                //begin of HTML message
        $message = "<html>
      <body bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">
            Hello, $name, your ad $title is 30 days old etc...
      </body>
    </html>";
       //end of message 
            $headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n" .
            'Reply-To:'.$_POST['email']."\r\n" .
            "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n".
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            mail($mail_to, "Your ad is 30 days old", $message, $headers);
        }
    ?>
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute your sendEmail function inside the while.  What's happening now is that it's going through all the returned rows, setting the variables, overwriting the variables, then it's sending the email once.  Try something like this.  Notice the if statement is now inside your while block.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo $row['name']." - ".$row['title']." - ".$row['email']."\n";
            echo $mail_to = $row['email'].", ";
            echo $title=$row["title"];
            echo $name=$row["name"];
            echo $idPost=$row["idPost"];
            echo $password=$row["password"];
            if (!empty($mail_to)){
                sendEmail($mail_to,$email,$name,$title,$idPost,$password);
            }
}
```

Now it will send the email, THEN process the next row.  Meaning it will send the email now for each row.

Comment: Additionally, you should stop using the mysql functions as those are now deprecated.  Look into using PDO or mysqli.